# Sorting Post Categories in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, posts

I am echoing out all the post categories that are a child of another category using child_of() and they are currently being sorted alphabetically.  Is there a way to sort the categories by popularity? (categories with the most posts are at the top of the list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found.  'orderby'=>count